# How to make two separate, independent columns (using html and css)

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to develop a small website using html and css. I'm rather new to css so I don't really know how to proceed in spite of having looked for it for quite a big while now.

What I'd like to do :
I have two youtube videos to integrate in my webpage. I want to divide my webpage in two columns (maybe more in the future) and put the first video in the center of the left column, the second video in the middle of the second column.

I've already tried using **float:left;** and also bootstrap but it doesn't center the videos the way I want (or maybe I just didn't find the way). I've also tried the html unordered list formatting but it didn't work out as expected either.

I don't want to scroll into each column, I just want some sort of positionning that lets the videos in the center even if we zoom in/out the webpage.

*It's my first question here so feel free to tell me if I do something wrong :)*

Comment: Could you please at least provide some mockup on how you want the page to look like?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I'd like it to be : http://s27.postimg.org/ggkzpm4f7/screenshot.jpg
This was made using float:left, float:right and position:relative, meaning that zooming in totally wrecks this magnificent, good-looking page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to divide your page in columns then you might want to look into bootstrap. It'll be easier to change the number of columns in the future.

Coming to the main question, in order to center the videos in each column, just apply 'margin: auto' on the columns. Here's a working example: [`http://codepen.io/xvariant/pen/bEKYEM`](http://codepen.io/xvariant/pen/bEKYEM)

```css
.row > div:first-child {
  background-color: #8E3E3E;
}
.row > div {
  background-color: #3E8E3E;
}
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}
.video-wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="video-wrapper">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uRT-DaL64Uo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
      <div class="video-wrapper">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uRT-DaL64Uo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works well, very nice. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the case you are trying to do. If so, here the bootstrap example:

CSS styles:

```
.width-400 { 
    width: 400px;
}
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="row-fluid no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="center-block width-400">
            <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F2iSzV50ACM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="center-block width-400">
            <!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F2iSzV50ACM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question. If so, I think this would solve your question.

I think you should create two columns in HTML like this:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column-left">
         Here you should embed your youtube video
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
         Here you should embed your second youtube video
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to create a CSS like this:

```
.columns {
    max-width:100%;
}

.column-left {
    max-width:50%;
    margin: auto;
}

.column-right {
    max-width:50%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Tried exactly what you told me and now the second video is below the first one. I don't really get it. I even tried to change the values of each max-width but it still doesn't seem to work so well.

Comment: Include this to the code.

.column-left, .column-right {
    float: left;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
columns:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple css to put two div in a row and align the second div to centre.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
  }

.container div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  margin:10px;
  }

.second {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"> First Youtube video
    </div>
  <div class="second"> Second Youtube video
    </div>
  </div>
```

Since you are new to css, I would suggest to use bootstrap instead of trying with your own css.